# override __init__ method to format initial value on modelform

Tags: django, django-forms, modelform

I have a `datetime` field. While loading the initial value, I want to format the value from `2014-04-12 13:00:00` to `April 12, 2014 1:00 pm`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be clearer about what you want to do. You mean you want to change the way the date is displayed? You don't do that in the form at all, especially not in the `__init__`. Displaying values is the job of the widget.

The [DateTimeWidget](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/forms/widgets/#datetimeinput) already accepts a `format` argument that controls the way the value is displayed. You can set this in the field declaration itself.

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    datetime = forms.DateTimeField(widget=forms.DateTimeInput(format="%B %d, %Y %I:%M%p"))
```

Comment: Damn man, I really should read the whole documentation. How do we specify this argument though `format='%d...'` ?